# How to remove quick links in Chrome for Android homepage?

Tags: chrome-for-android

> [image]

How do I remove these quick links from Chrome for Android app?

Comment: I have not found an option to remove the icons, however you can configure certain options via `chrome://flags`. Search for `ntp` (stands for new tab page).

Answer (score 4):

To remove one at a time:

1. Long-press on a link ( I think the correct name is shortcut).
2. When a menu appears, click Remove.

To remove all:

1. Click on the 3-dot, then Settings.
2. Click on Home page, enable it if it was disabled.
3. Click on "Open this page". Enter `about:blank` or any website you would to open when you open Chrome. You might have to restart Chrome for the changes to take effect.

However, they will re-appear again based on the history.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Play Store and uninstall Chrome. It will uninstall the updated version. Then go to your Chrome. Shortcuts never appear again. You can update Chrome. 100% true solution, fixed my own Chrome.

Comment: Aside from Chrome will revert to the original version if it is a system app (otherwise, the app will be really uninstalled and need to be reinstalled), I think this will have the same problem that it only clears the links temporarily, and will reappear after some usages.